# get json Data from store Extjs

Tags: extjs, store

Is there any way I can use my stored data on the Grid Panel ExtJS exactly as I load it:
for example:

```
var data = ["value1", "value2"]
Store.loadData (date);

data = Store.getData ();
// data = ["value1", "value2"]
```

Comment: This is rather a site for programming errors, not suggestions how to do things. Try things yourself first and if you encounter errors ask here

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, and why. ExtJS stores do exist for a good reason.

Comment: I want to get the store data and then change them
@Alexander

Comment: @mohammadhefazi you can change the data directly in the store. Why would you need to extract it?